# Create a customized Pivot Table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, html-table, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table that was previously created using SAS, but I want to have it in Python with almost the same font and color.

I wrote the following code. It gives me the general table, but I was wondering if there is any way I can make it more beautiful by changing lines, color, font and dimension.

```
filtered_table=mytable[mytable['country'] != "Japan"]

def t_design(a):
 pvt_table = pd.pivot_table(filtered_table, index=[a], columns= ['years'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
 pvt_table.loc['Total'].pvt_table.sum()
 html_file=pvt_table.to_html()
 title= f"<h1>My table Title for {a} </h1>"
 html_file= title + html_file
 with open(f'my file direction/{a}.html','w')  as f:
  f.write(html_file)

t_design('job_code')
t_design('city_code')
```

Also, the final table shows years like float number (eg. 2024.0 instead of 2024) I tried to use str(['year']) or int(['year']) but non of them works.
Another issue is that it puts 'country' at the top of the years. I tried to move it outside the function, but still, it writes it as the header of 'years'

Comment: You can put CSS in the HTML file to customize how the table looks.

Comment: Could you provide more information? I worked for a short time with html but I don't have any experience with CSS.

Comment: You may want to use Jinja templating, but we cannot reliably show you how to do this unless you show a minimum reproducible example. Note that [to_html has a `classes` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) for styling.

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service, we can't teach you HTML and CSS here. You can read tutorials like https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Comment: Thank you @Reinderien and Barmar. I think I got the insight of how to add other parts of the html codes to my table to make it look better.